# GCC compilation problem - fatal error: cannot find 'ld'

Tags: c, gcc

When I run the following code I get 
`collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'
compilation terminated.` as output. My GCC version is `gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0`. It seems it is unable to locate `ld` module. I don't know how to proceed ahead.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

int main(){
    char *stderr = "/home/vs/Desktop/test/output.txt";
    char *args[] = {"/usr/bin/gcc",
                    "-Wall",
                    "-O2",
                    "-std=gnu11",
                    "-fomit-frame-pointer",
                    "/home/vs/Desktop/test/Solution.c",
                    "-o",
                    "/home/vs/Desktop/test/Solution",
                    "-lm",
                    NULL};
    char *env[]  = {"LANG=en_US.UTF-8", "LANGUAGE=en_US:en", "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8", NULL};

    int fd;
    if(0 > (fd = open(stderr, O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC))) perror("open");
    if(0 > dup2(fd, 2)) perror("dup");
    if(fd != 2) close(fd);

    int x = execve("/usr/bin/gcc", args, env);
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ld` is the traditional name of the UNIX linker, and the GCC system indeed provides a linker by that name.  The diagnostic you report therefore suggests that your GCC installation is incomplete or corrupt.  I suggest removing it completely and reinstalling, via your system's package management tools.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it does not work. But I have tried manual compilation and it works. It is this program that doesn't work.

Comment: Why, @John?  That would request linking a library named `libd`.  Although that would make additional work for the linker (probably looking for and failing to find such a library), I don't see any reason to think that it would make a difference as to whether the linker is found.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Perhaps my comment was inappropriate. I didn't read the question fully. A missing ld reported by the collect2 utility (used by gcc) implies that the linker (ld) is not found in /bin or /usr/bin/ locations.

Comment: @John I just wanted to thank you for your comment. In my case, I was doing a compilation on an ARM box running Linux with an old version of GCC and this error was driving me nuts, since `ld` _was_ on the path. But that path wasn't being propagated properly to GCC! Symlinking `/usr/bin/ld` to where `ld` actually was solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the same compilation command works when issued via a shell, but fails when issued programmatically as shown, the problem is very likely with the environment you are supplying to `execve()`.  Note in particular that the environment array provided to that function represents the *whole* environment for the command, not merely extra entries.

Particularly relevant in that regard is that the provided environment does not include a `PATH` variable. The exec'd process will therefore need to use a fully-qualifed path to any commands it wants to launch in turn, such as `ld`.  If it does not do so, then just such an error as you report will occur. Adding a `PATH` to the specified environment should resolve the issue.  You could copy that from the program's own environment, or, more easily, insert a default path.  For example,

```
    // ...

    char *env[]  = {
        "PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin",  // <--- this
        "LANG=en_US.UTF-8",
        "LANGUAGE=en_US:en",
        "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8",
        NULL
    };

    // ...
```

Comment: [@John's comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886330/gcc-compilation-problem-fatal-error-cannot-find-ld#comment94621045_53886330) is actually interesting: apparently, GCC, on its own, will try to search for `ld` under `/bin` or `/usr/bin`, no matter what the `$PATH` is set to. Some Linux distributions (especially on ARM-based embedded devices) _may_ place `ld` elsewhere. The simplest solution is not to change your code, but rather just to place a symlink from `/usr/bin/ld` to wherever `ld` actually is in your system.

Comment: That's interesting, @GwynethLlewelyn.  However, in this case, the same command the OP was trying to execute programmatically worked as expected when run from a shell, which is inconsistent with the it arising from (just) the linker not being found at a particular hardcoded path.  I would also contend that although one may well want to control the executable search path, it is very rare that one actually wants to execute a command without any search path at all, so they probably did want to modify their code even if there was another alternative.

Comment: On second thoughts, you may be right; I tried the 'trick' on two different ARM-based devices: a Synology NAS and a Raspberry Pi Zero W. The former never finished the compilation (it's hard to find an up-to-date fully working GCC stack for Synology); the latter was a bit better, but still failed way too often for my taste. Eventually I gave up and just cross-compiled from macOS to both devices :-P